# Send a second follow-up to inquire about interview success?

Tags: interview

I interviewed for a lecturer position a month and a half ago, and was told that the decision would be made about one month after my interview.  I was also told that I would be informed either way, but have yet to hear back.  A week ago I sent a follow up email, asking if a decision had been made, but didn't receive a response.  Is it appropriate to send another follow up, or should I just sit tight?  I have a feeling I didn't get the position, but I'd like to know for sure so that I can start planning other options.

Comment: Why the downvote?  If the question is inappropriate that's fine, but please let me know why

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with following up a second time.  This issue has been covered by some good questions at Workplace, for example here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p I don't think this is academia-specific, really.  Though I don't see a reason to downvote your post.

Answer (score 1):

You won't accomplish anything by sending another email. The department hasn't forgotten that they interviewed you.

Comment: Probably not. But they might have forgotten to send him the information they promised.

Answer (score -2):

They probably drop balls there regularly and don't want you to know that! Why can't you send a hand written note thanking them again and singing their praises? They will remember you if their pet candidate pulls out for a better offer. Their pet candidate may be stringing them along, hoping for something better. Don't appear to be in a rush or say they did not follow through. Appear eager and not stressed out. They know why you are sending a snail mail... because you want the position! There is no shame in trying everything. You are getting a taste of the disorganization of the organization you hope to join. Knock on the back door and say hello and thank you again for the honor of being interviewed by someone so prominent who has such an amazing job at such a prominent place. Was it an honor to get the interview or not?